# Efficient mechanism to uncompress a file in S3 on the fly and stream back to s3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gzip, boto3

I have a gzipped csv file in s3 having the compressed volume around 85GB and uncompressed volume equivalent to 805GB. I need to decompress this file and persist the decompressed file back to S3. Due to limitations in my execution environment, I need to decompress the compressed file data on the fly and persist it back to S3. Currently, I'm using [smart-open](https://pypi.org/project/smart-open/) and following code snippet to do the work, and it works pretty well, on handling streaming and decompressing. As minimizing execution time is crucial in my task, I want to know whether there are methods to improve this code or some better mechanism to handle this task.

```
import smart_open

transport_params = {"min_part_size": 200 * 1024 * 1024}

with smart_open.open('s3://outputbucket/decompressed.csv', 'w', transport_params=transport_params) as fout:
    for line in smart_open.open('s3://inputbucket/compressed.csv.gz', 'rb', encoding='utf8'):
        fout.write(line)
```

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/amazon-kinesis-firehose-data-transformation-with-aws-lambda/

Comment: You're almost certainly constrained by network bandwidth. If you're not running on an EC2 instance, in the same region as the S3 bucket, you should be.

Comment: Also, is your file a line-oriented text file? If not, then the way that you're copying is likely to corrupt it.

Comment: @Parsifal absolutely yes, I'm aware everything will be constrained by network bandwidth, so the script is executed on a ec2 instance

Comment: @Parsifal and As it is a csv file data is line-oriented. Thanks for the response